# Create dataframe that counts instances over time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
Asset name  Risk Chief Risks    Risk category   Risk start  Risk end
0   Stanton County, KS, US (Corn)   Temperature high    2020-06-25 18:00:00 2020-07-10 00:00:00
1   Seward County, KS, US (Corn)    Temperature high    2020-06-25 18:00:00 2020-07-10 00:00:00
2   Hansford County, TX, US (Corn)  Temperature high    2020-06-29 12:00:00 2020-07-02 00:00:00
3   Haskell County, KS, US (Corn)   Temperature high    2020-06-25 18:00:00 2020-07-10 00:00:00
4   Hale County, TX, US (Corn)  Temperature high    2020-06-29 12:00:00 2020-07-02 00:00:00
5   Greeley County, KS, US (Corn)   Temperature high    2020-06-25 18:00:00 2020-07-01 00:00:00
```

I have created a new dataframe that looks like this, taken from today's date + 14 days.

```
25 Jun  26 Jun  27 Jun  28 Jun  29 Jun  30 Jun  01 Jul  02 Jul  03 Jul  04 Jul  05 Jul  06 Jul  07 Jul  08 Jul  09 Jul  10 Jul
```

I want to fill each day with a count that corresponds to the days that the risk is high. For example, the first city has high risk from 6-25 through 7-10. Therefore, each day would have 1 for the count. The third city has high risk from 6-29 to 7-2. Therefore, it would only add 1 to those specific days for the count. First off, how would I accomplish this? Second off, is there a more elegant way of doing/presenting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
# Data Setup
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""Asset name  Risk Chief Risks    Risk category   Risk start  Risk end
0   Stanton County, KS, US  (Corn)   Temperature high    2020-06-25 18:00:00  2020-07-10 00:00:00
1   Seward County, KS, US  (Corn)    Temperature high    2020-06-25 18:00:00  2020-07-10 00:00:00
2   Hansford County, TX, US  (Corn)  Temperature high    2020-06-29 12:00:00  2020-07-02 00:00:00
3   Haskell County, KS, US  (Corn)   Temperature high    2020-06-25 18:00:00  2020-07-10 00:00:00
4   Hale County, TX, US  (Corn)  Temperature high    2020-06-29 12:00:00  2020-07-02 00:00:00
5   Greeley County, KS, US  (Corn)   Temperature high    2020-06-25 18:00:00  2020-07-01 00:00:00"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python", index_col=0)

# Date Range
df["Risk start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Risk start"])
min_date = df["Risk start"].min().date()
df["Risk end"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Risk end"])
max_date = df["Risk end"].max().date()
dates = pd.date_range(min_date, max_date)

# New Output DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=dates, columns=df['Asset name'], data=[[0]*len(df)]*len(dates))
length = (df["Risk end"] - df["Risk start"]).dt.ceil('d').dt.days

# Iterate the cities and assign value 1 at the appropriate locations
for city_ind in length.index:
    sd = df["Risk start"].dt.floor('d').iloc[city_ind]
    ed = length[city_ind]
    df1.loc[sd:sd+pd.to_timedelta("{} days".format(ed)), df["Asset name"].iloc[city_ind]] = 1
print(df1.T.to_string())
```

Output:

```
                             2020-06-25  2020-06-26  2020-06-27  2020-06-28  2020-06-29  2020-06-30  2020-07-01  2020-07-02  2020-07-03  2020-07-04  2020-07-05  2020-07-06  2020-07-07  2020-07-08  2020-07-09  2020-07-10
Asset name                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Stanton County, KS, US            1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1
Seward County, KS, US             1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1
Hansford County, TX, US           0           0           0           0           1           1           1           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
Haskell County, KS, US            1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1
Hale County, TX, US               0           0           0           0           1           1           1           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
Greeley County, KS, US            1           1           1           1           1           1           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
```

Note how at the end I'm taking the transpose. In my opinion, it's more elegant to express this with the dates as the index and the cities as the columns, but I guess that's up to you.

Comment: Awesome! This is great. Is there a way to then sum all of the values for a particular day? The end goal is to simply have the total sum for each day, regardless of where it came from. Thanks for this answer though.

Comment: `df1.sum(1).to_frame().T` ... think this accomplishes that

Comment: Hey man. I loaded in the data for a new day today and the script is giving me this error: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds. any idea why that would occur? I noticed that when I printed out df1 before the for loop every single entry is zero for some, but not sure why.

Comment: The following would produce that error: e.g. `df.iloc[23423]`. I have no doubt that I could help you fix the problem, but it's pretty difficult to do without more information. When df1 is instantiated, it is with an array of zeros so that's to be expected.

Comment: What additional info do you need?

Comment: what df looks like entering the for loop and the full traceback for the error

Comment: Entering the for loop: https://imgur.com/a/qx04foI. Full error: https://imgur.com/a/FQB8YPx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216744/discussion-between-cosmic-inquiry-and-eli-turasky).